# Checking downtime with XSLT 1.0 with start/end + working time given

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have two dates given in XML - start and end.

Then I have a timeframe given, Monday to Friday from 8 to 17h.

I need to check how many minutes of the given start/end day fall in between the timeframe.

i.e.:
Start: 01.02.2018, 6:00h
End: 10.02.2018, 6:00
Timeframe: Monday to Friday 8 - 17h
So the result would be 9 hours a day and 8 working days, so 9*24*8

Currently I am able to check if a given day falls between the timeframe. However, with datings which partly fall in between the timeframe I struggle. How would I best solve this with XSLT 1.0?

Comment: Never use dd.mm.yyyy or mm.dd.yyyy dates unless you really want to confuse people! With XML you should always use ISO dates, YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library of date-handling functions/templates for XSLT 1.0 at www.exslt.org; whether it's available for your chosen XSLT 1.0 processor is another question.

Better is to move to XSLT 2.0/3.0 which has rich functionality for date and time handling.